# How to access field names of javascript object in HTML passed in from backend?

Tags: html, node.js, express, swig-template

Example:

var obj={name:bob,
        }

I want to access not the value of name i.e. bob instead an array containing keys of obj like [name].

```
<h1>{{ pagename|title }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for author in collections %}
  <li >
    {{ author.uno }}
    {{ author.subject }}
    <script>
        var array =  Object.keys(author).map((key) => key) ;  
        document.write('<p>' + array + '</p>');
      </script>


    {% for element in author %}
       <li >
             {{element  }} 


      </li>
    {% endfor %}


  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here collections is an array of objects passed in from backend i.e. nodejs.
Author is a javascript object.
I have tried getting desired result using logic inside script tag.
But it is not printing anything on webpage.
I have also tried placing {{}} at different positions without getting fruitful results.

Comment: There're some weird things here. First there's a syntax error here `var obj={name:bob; }` , the semicolon inside the object declaration would break your code. Then why would you  make a script with a document write, instead of just writing it with your templating engine. Then, why would you map an array to the exact same array, it's like sayin `x = x`.

Comment: With the phrase 'Here collections is an array of objects passed in from backend' I think you're not fully understanding what's executing on the back-end and what on the front-end. So, everything wrapped inside {{ }} and {% %} is running on you nodejs backend, it has the node scope and can see the variables you sent to the templating engine, everything outside that is sent to the client and executed on the browser, here you have no access to your `author` var because there is no way the browser, inside the script tag, could know the value of author, which is a variable of your templating engine

Answer (score 0):

update: I forgot you're using swig-template. Here is my suggestion:

```
//backend :
const author = { /* author object */ };
author.keys = Object.keys(author).join(', ');
swig.renderFile('/path/to/template.html',{ author });
```

and then, put it in template.htm;

```
{{ author.subject }}
{{ author.keys }}
{% for element in author %}
   <li >
         {{element  }} 


  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks kai .  but on trying this am getting this error :                                                  Cannot convert undefined or null to object
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: thanks again but, I am passing an array of objects from backend to html.Applying the above logic to the whole array in backend wont be feasible. Is there any way to acess field names of the objects in collection array in front end directly?